# ETH stuck after cancelled due to "out of gas

Tags: cpp-ethereum, jaxx

I have seen another questions with the same problem but the answers given there do not work for me and therefor put my question here again.

I sent 0.5 ETH and 0.1 ETH from my Jaxx Wallet to Poloniex. Both transactions were cancelled due to "out of gas". According to many people the amount never left the wallet and should bounce back. It did for the 0.1 ETH but NOT for the 0.5 ETH. I tried everything, delete cache, sync with new phone, emailed Jaxx, emailed ETH but no one can help. This is the TX 0x7f75ed41a57b356c3df0d6828386d24311cef78a6e74fd0bccf38074315fad00. The weird thing is that my balance shown on the blockchain corresponds with the one in my wallet so as far as Jaxx is concerned it is synced correctly, but it is not. the 0.5 ETH is not shown.

I hope someone can help me with this. According to Etherium this should not be possible, but as you can see it can.

Comment: Why are you saying 0.5 ETH didn´t bounce back? It never leaved from your balance in that transaction

Comment: It did leave my balance, thats the point. It left my Jaxx wallet so my balance is 0.5 ETH less. After sending my balance was and still is 0.5 ETH less. The 0.1 ETH also left my Jaxx balance but within a few hours reappeard as a payment received. If technically it never left, then I hope someone can help met to have it re-appear in my wallet since it is not there now . Jaxx does not give a clear answer beside a general story about congestion of ETH network.